# MDX queries. How can to solve "IN" in "where" part

Tags: where-clause, mdx, olap

I have sql query  and i need this query execute in olap cube .

```
select count(distinct mi.id) from  [MTD_DEV].[dbo].[MenuItemAttributes] as m
  inner join  [dbo].[MenuItemOlds] as  mi
  on mi.id = m.MenuItemId
  inner join [dbo].[RestaurantlistItems] as rl
  on rl.RestaurantId = mi.RestaurantId
  where  m.AttributeId = 31 and rl.RestaurantListId = 69 and mi.PeriodId = 99 and m.MenuItemId in (select MenuItemId from  [MTD_DEV].[dbo].[MenuItemAttributes] where AttributeId = 6
```

and i have working mdx query and **I need to add operator 'IN'**  or something another solution for this query

> ```
>   SELECT CROSSJOIN( 
>     {[Measures].[Menu Item Olds Count],[Measures].[Restaurantlist Items Count]},
>     {[Periods].[Id].[99],[Periods].[Id].[93],[Periods].[Id].[75]}) ON COLUMNS,
>     {[Menu Item Olds].[id]} ON ROWS
>      FROM [MTD DEV]
>      where (
>      {[Restaurant Lists].[Id].[69]},
>      {[Attributes].[Id].[6]} ,
>      {[Attribute Categories].[Id].[5]} -- or can use the same parameter {[Attributes].[Id].[31]}
>            )
> ```
>
> for better understanding:
>   https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3rw0YPItJIIa3FfNEtrVC04SVU/view?usp=sharing

**Additional Comments to questio**n

In ms sql I have to slice MenuItemOlds by some parameter  m.AttributeId = 31
annd then from result I have to slice again for parameter AttributeId = 6.
In Sql it looks like this:

```
select count(distinct mi.id) from  [MTD_DEV].[dbo].[MenuItemAttributes] as m
  inner join  [dbo].[MenuItemOlds] as  mi on mi.id = m.MenuItemId
  where  m.AttributeId = 31 and m.MenuItemId in (select MenuItemId from  [MTD_DEV].[dbo].[MenuItemAttributes] where AttributeId = 6
```

I have problem in OLAP Cube. 
How I see to solve this problem :

1.I get all data where AttributeId = 31

```
 SELECT CROSSJOIN( 
    {[Measures].[Menu Item Olds Count],[Measures].[Restaurantlist Items Count]},
    {[Periods].[Id].[99],[Periods].[Id].[93],[Periods].[Id].[75]}) ON COLUMNS,
    {[Menu Item Olds].[id]} ON ROWS
     FROM [MTD DEV]
     where ({[Attributes].[Id].[31]})
```

the result of this  -  all catering  menu items

2. After this  , in this collection of Menu Items,  I need to find all menu items where  {[Attributes].[Id].[6]} (kids menu)

When  i am trying to execute such query :

```
 SELECT CROSSJOIN( 
    {[Measures].[Menu Item Olds Count],[Measures].[Restaurantlist Items Count]},
    {[Periods].[Id].[99],[Periods].[Id].[93],[Periods].[Id].[75]}) ON COLUMNS,
    {[Menu Item Olds].[id]} ON ROWS
     FROM [MTD DEV]
     where (
     {[Attributes].[Id].[6]} ,
     {[Attributes].[Id].[31]}
           )
```

I get result , in which i have Menu items with AttributeId.[6] + menuItem with attributeId.[31]
for example:

---

count of  menu items with AttributeId.[6] = 11000 items

---

count of  menu items with AttributeId.[31] = 724000items

---

and result  is 724000+11000 = 735000  but i don`t need it

---

i need to find all  items with  AttributeId.[31], and  in this  collection i need to find  items with AttributeId.[6]
The right result of query must be less than 11000 items

Comment: What do you need to add "IN" for?  You already have {[Attributes].[Id].[6]}.

Comment: because its not working correctly for me it does not return any result. if you looking on db scheme we have MenuitemItributes  and this is table many-to-many between Menuitems and Attributes. and when i set                                             {[Attributes].[Id].[6]} ,{[Attribute Categories].[Id].[5]} we have not such item where AttributeId and AttributeCategoryId with such parameters. we have not rows , where {[Attributes].[Id].[6]} and {[Attributes].[Id].[31]} in one moment

Comment: I am not getting your question. Do you want to replace some part of your query with "IN" OR do you want to add to your query an "IN" clause? If so, which part from SQL query do you want to be added with "IN"?

Comment: Im with Sourav - the answer to the question seems to be in the question.

Comment: I am added additional information to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `NonEmpty` with `intersect` work as an alternative?

```
SELECT 
    {
      [Measures].[Menu Item Olds Count]
     ,[Measures].[Restaurantlist Items Count]
    }
  * 
    {
      [Periods].[Id].[99]
     ,[Periods].[Id].[93]
     ,[Periods].[Id].[75]
    } ON COLUMNS
 ,Intersect
  (
    NonEmpty
    (
      [Menu Item Olds].[id].[id].MEMBERS
     ,(
        [Attributes].[Id].[31]
       ,{
          [Measures].[Menu Item Olds Count]
         ,[Measures].[Restaurantlist Items Count]
        }
      )
    )
   ,NonEmpty
    (
      [Menu Item Olds].[id].[id].MEMBERS
     ,(
        [Attributes].[Id].[6]
       ,{
          [Measures].[Menu Item Olds Count]
         ,[Measures].[Restaurantlist Items Count]
        }
      )
    )
  ) ON ROWS
FROM [MTD DEV];
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a classical case for [`Exists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144936.aspx), slightly complicated as you have a many-to-many relationship between `Menu Item Olds` and `Attributes`:

```
SELECT CROSSJOIN( 
    {[Measures].[Menu Item Olds Count],[Measures].[Restaurantlist Items Count]},
    {[Periods].[Id].[99],[Periods].[Id].[93],[Periods].[Id].[75]})
    ON COLUMNS,
    Exists(Exists([Menu Item Olds].[id].[id].Members, 
                  {[Attributes].[Id].[31]}
                 ), 
           {[Attributes].[Id].[6]}
          )
    ON ROWS
FROM [MTD DEV]
```

Comment: Maybe it`s right solution , but when I run query with the same construction , I get error 'System.OutOfMemoryException'. In the server where i ran  , had 122 gigabytes of RAM