# MDX to count common members - EXISTS alternative

Tags: ssas, mdx, exists

Let me describe the issue giving example from [Adventure Works] cube.

Following MDX returns count of 17473

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Internet Order Count] } ON COLUMNS,

[Internet Sales Order Details].[Sales Order Number] on ROWS

FROM [Adventure Works])

WHERE ( [Sales Reason].[Sales Reason].&[1] -- price
```

and following returns count of 3515

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Internet Order Count] } ON COLUMNS ,

[Internet Sales Order Details].[Sales Order Number] on ROWS

FROM [Adventure Works]

WHERE ( [Sales Reason].[Sales Reason].&[2]) -- on promotion
```

I would like to count [Sales Order Number] which are common in [Sales Reason].&[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26869096/mdx-queries-how-can-to-solve-in-in-where-part) and [Sales Reason].&[2]

SQL equivalent would be:

```
select count(distinct f.SalesOrderNumber)
from FactInternetSales f
join FactInternetSalesReason fs 
on f.SalesOrderNumber = fs.SalesOrderNumber and f.SalesOrderLineNumber = fs.SalesOrderLineNumber
where fs.SalesReasonKey = 1 and fs.SalesOrderNumber in
      (select SalesOrderNumber from FactInternetSalesReason fs1 where fs1.SalesReasonKey = 2)

-- sales reason 1 = 17473
-- sales reason 2 = 3515
-- common 1689
```

I got common count using following mdx:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[common] AS count

   (  exists ( exists ([Internet Sales Order Details].[Sales Order Number].[Sales Order Number].Members,
         [Sales Reason].[Sales Reason].&[1],"Internet Orders" 
         ),
         [Sales Reason].[Sales Reason].&[2],"Internet Orders" 
        )
    )

SELECT NON EMPTY [Measures].[common] ON COLUMNS

FROM [Adventure Works] 

-- 1689
```

But use of EXISTS is rather slow for my requirement. Please suggest an alternative.

Also please see related thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26869096/mdx-queries-how-can-to-solve-in-in-where-part)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try adding both reasons to the `WHERE` clause as a single set:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[Internet Order Count]} ON COLUMNS
 ,[Internet Sales Order Details].[Sales Order Number] ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE 
  {
    [Sales Reason].[Sales Reason].&[2]
   ,[Sales Reason].[Sales Reason].&[1]
  };
```

Here is an alternative that runs faster, only looks at the common orders, and does not use the `EXISTS` function:

```
WITH 
  SET [AllOrders] AS 
    [Internet Sales Order Details].[Sales Order Number].[Sales Order Number].MEMBERS 
  SET [OrdersIntersection] AS 
    Intersect
    (
      NonEmpty
      (
        [AllOrders]
       ,{
          (
            [Sales Reason].[Sales Reason].&[1]
           ,[Measures].[Internet Order Count]
          )
        }
      )
     ,NonEmpty
      (
        [AllOrders]
       ,{
          (
            [Sales Reason].[Sales Reason].&[2]
           ,[Measures].[Internet Order Count]
          )
        }
      )
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[commonCount] AS 
    [OrdersIntersection].Count 
SELECT 
  //NON EMPTY //<<not needed
    [Measures].[commonCount] ON COLUMNS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Comment: I need 'Internet Order Count' which are common in 'Sales Reason' 1 and 2 not a count of their total.

Comment: @PrakashGautam - I misunderstood your question. I have added an alternative to my post. Your `exists` script runs in 1.1secs on my machine whereas my intersection version runs in 0.8secs.

Comment: Thanks @whytheq, Intersect does run faster then Exists.